# Check if logged in user liked a page on Facebook API using JS?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-like

Im currently working on a project that require to have fan like a page before he can see several content on the site.

The webpage is not an app in Facebook, it's outside facebook. We will not use PHP or backend code, we will only use FrontEnd

I have finished the user login check to check if user is logged in or not.

I am now stuck with the check if user is a fan of our page. I try to use the function page.IsFan, but somehow it needs to have an UID.

The FQL approach is not possible due to the same reason.

Also another problem is with the appID of our page. I try to google of how to get the appID for page, but the search is mixed up with useless contents.

Is there anyway to either get the UID or check if user liked ourpage without UID?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you need to fetch that information each time the page is loaded, or just catch the "like" event, as it happens?

Comment: the page is only load once. So i do not need to worry about it. but some time there are return users, so I need to check if the user has already like the page or not somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use backend code from your Facebook iFrame fan page because you have to inspect the signed_request variable that is sent in the HTTP POST request to your page, as this variable won't be available via javascript, and subscribing to edge.create in javascript won't work because the page does a full refresh when the user clicks the like button and that event won't fire.

If you are forcing the user to authenticate with your app (which is not nessary if you inspected signed_request variable, you can use a FQL query or graph api request and instead of specifiying their user id, just use "me".  something like: `select field from table where uid = me()`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you provide a UID you won't be able to know whether the user has liked the page previously. However, you can use `FB.Event.subscribe` to find out when the user does like the item, by subscribing to the `edge.create` event:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    alert("liked the item");
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/rmrE4/

Comment: Is there anyway to get the UID?

Comment: @DucDigital If they have logged in, then yes. You can get the UID with `getLoginStatus` in that case: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: I have use this function in my script, but mostly they have no response.session object. When i do a console log on the response. it gave me a NotConnected (those people who logged in but not connect to your app). It's a fan page, so how can I get the info about this? how can be authorize to get the users from a fan page?